# How to call strings in fragment from activity?

Tags: android, string, android-fragments, android-activity, textview

I have Activity A that has String that updates every 1s.
I also have Fragment B which has a Button and a TextView.

When I press my button in Fragment B I want to get String from Activity A to my TextView.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit(); 
editor.putString("DATA_NAME", "YOUR_DATA");  
editor.commit();  

On the Button Click

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);  
String restoredData = prefs.getString("DATA_NAME", DEFAULT);     
yourTextView.setText(restoredData );
```

Comment: whilst it is nice that you have posted code, you should always give an explanation to your code. Thank you!

Comment: Using sharedPreferences doesn't seem to be the best way since the string is changing every second. I managed to do it with an interface!